# How to get Microsoft Teams context property hostClientType

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've been trying to get hostClientType from Teams context. I get context with the code below, but hostClientType is not populated / available. I need to distinguish between running in teams webapp or teams desktop app and think the property is therefore. Any help is appreciated.

```
microsoftTeams.getContext(function (context) {
  alert(context.hostClientType) // undefined
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not in the object that .getContext returns.

Try navigator.userAgent - it will return something like: `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Teams/1.1.00.22163 Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Electron/2.0.4 Safari/537.36"`.